# Devolver true o false PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Me percate que la validación no funcionaba y que no importa los datos que ingrese desde el mantenedor este código siempre devuelve 1. Lo que busco es que devuelva 0 si es que la consulta sql no devolvió ningún resultado.

```
if (!$cnn) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }else {
    $nombre_usuario = $_POST['txt_nombre_admin']; //Nombre del usuario
    $contraseña_usuario = $_POST['txt_password_admin'];//Contraseña usuario
    $privilegio_usuario = $_POST['sel_privilegio']; //Nivel del usuario

    $rs = mysqli_prepare($cnn,"SELECT privilegio FROM usuarios WHERE (nombre = ? and password = ? and privilegio = ?)");
    $ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rs, "ssi", $nombre_usuario, $contraseña_usuario, $privilegio_usuario);
    $ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($rs); //Siempre da 1

    if ($ok == false) {
      echo $ok; 
    }else {
      echo $ok;
    }
```

Comment: Sebastián, cuando uses funciones PHP lee lo que dice el apartado **Valores devueltos** de esa función en el Manual. En el caso de `mysqli_stmt_execute` dice esto textualmente: [*Devuelve `TRUE` en caso de éxito o `FALSE` en caso de error.*](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). La ejecución puede ser correcta `TRUE` pero no devolver ningún resultado. Para verificar si hay registros lo correcto sería que hagas una consulta con `COUNT(*)` y verifiques si la misma devolvió filas.

Comment: Si miras la documentación http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php, verás que la función devuelve true o false dependiendo de si tuvo éxito o no. Luego que retorne 1 no indica si encontró registros o no, solo indica que no hay error.

Comment: Entendí perfecto gracias por la aclaración!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comprobación de la existencia de datos no puede ser dependiente de el éxito o el fracaso de una función cualquiera. Lo correcto sería revisar los mismos datos. Puedes hacerlo por ejemplo mediante una consulta `COUNT(*)`.  Si te interesa información de alguna columna de la tabla, entonces puedes hacer un `SELECT` normal de esas columnas y determinar al mismo tiempo la existencia de datos mediante `num_rows`.  En cualquiera de los dos casos la comprobación se estaría haciendo sobre los datos en sí.

Propongo este código:

```
$ok=FALSE;
if (!$cnn) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    $nombre_usuario = ( empty ($_POST['txt_nombre_admin']) )   ? NULL : $_POST['txt_nombre_admin'];
    $clave_usuario = ( empty ($_POST['txt_password_admin']) )  ? NULL : $_POST['txt_password_admin'];
    $privilegio_usuario = ( empty ($_POST['sel_privilegio']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['sel_privilegio'];

    if ($nombre_usuario && $clave_usuario && $privilegio_usuario){
        $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = ? AND password = ? AND privilegio = ?";
        if ($rs = mysqli_prepare($cnn,$sql)){
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($rs, "ssi", $nombre_usuario, $clave_usuario, $privilegio_usuario);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($rs);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($rs, $numFilas);
            $ok= ($numFilas > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        }else{
            echo "Error preparando la consulta";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No se pasaron los datos completos en el POST";
    }
}
echo $ok;
```

En un código controlado, que informa siempre de lo que ha ocurrido. Además, verifica los datos que hay en POST mediante operadores ternarios. Tiene la variable `$ok` en `FALSE` por defecto y sólo cambiará cuando haya filas en la consulta.